# How to permanently change the default working path of julia?

Tags: julia

I was able to temporarily change it with the following command, but after reboot the working path still changes to C drive.

```
cd("D:\\jl files”）
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is explained in the Julia Manual [Getting Started](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/#man-getting-started) section the simplest thing to do is to add the:

```
cd("D:\\jl files")
```

line to your `~/.julia/config/startup.jl` file (this is a Linux path; if the file does not exist then you should create it with this single line). Since you are on Windows then `~` part should be replaced by default is your user profile folder (it should be possible to check it with `ENV["USERPROFILE"]` command in Julia). However, if you have a custom installation the `.julia` folder can be placed in some other folder so you need to check it on your system.